# Result of LWP::Simple get is truncated

Tags: perl

I'm using perl to perform a get request on a url, and the results appear to be truncated.

If I run

```
curl myurl | wc -l
```

the result is 1823, and if I create the following file foo.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $url = 'myurl';

use LWP::Simple;
my $content = get $url;
die "Couldn't get $url" unless defined $content;
print $content;
```

and run

```
./foo.pl | wc -l
```

the result varies from around 1300 to occasionally 1823. Manually inspecting the output shows that the output is broken mid-line when using perl.

What can be causing this?

Comment: Does the `curl` always work? Could it just be a dodgy server? Have you looked at the `Content-length` header?

Comment: We cannot reproduce your problem, give more information.

Comment: I believe the server we are using may have a bug that causes it to close the socket early when the close connection header is set. Is there a way to specify that this header should be unset?

Comment: A workaround in my case is to use `system("curl $url");`, but I would still like to know how to tell get not to have the connection closed if this is indeed the problem.

Comment: Minor correction: to get the output in the workaround, you need to do `my $content = \`curl $url\``

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/dist/LWP-Curl/

Comment: Can you check the result code when the output is truncated? Maybe it's not 200 but 206 Partial Content or that like. I'm not sure how LWP::Simple deals with that. You may try LWP::UserAgent (without Simple).

Comment: Btw, so long as your `$url` is something you set within the script, ```curl $url``` is OK. But if there's any chance you might allow that to be set from user input on the command-line or some such, you should consider using something like `open my $h, '|', 'curl', $url` instead to avoid someone from injecting a shell command into your script by passing a URL like `http://localhost;rm -rf *`.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you turn buffering off? I also agree with Karsten S. in checking the http headers for erroneous codes. Finally, I'd also try storing the contents into an array just to see what happens.

To turn off buffering, you could simply place a `$|++` at the top of your script after your `use` statements. Again, a shot in the dark.

To examine the http headers, you can use `CGI`. Here's a little site with a good example on how to get the headers from the request:

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t24118-re-lwp-simple-header-information-problems.html

Finally, try using an array, `@contents`, to store the contents from the webserver instead of a scalar, `$contents`. I've had times in the past where something is passed from the remote server that Perl misinterprets as a list. I'm not sure if `LWP::Simple` accounts for these times but it can't hurt to try. You might only be getting one part of the data and the rest is either getting overwritten or ignored altogether. Placing the data into an array could help determine if that is happening.